# Transfer variable type to another variable in R

Tags: r

I'd like to transfer the variable type from one variable to the other, where the variables are vectors.

for example x is numeric,  y is character but I want it to be the same as x, how to do this? Same if x is integer etc.

pseudo code:

```
y <- set_variable_type(y,get_variable_type(x))
```

Comment: `class(y) <- class(x)`? This assumes that coercion is done correctly, which is not always the case. For instance, if `y <- c("1", "a")`, then `class(y) <- "integer"` will correctly convert `"1"` to `1`, and `"a"` will become `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has the potential for some errors to crop up. Like @r2evans mentioned converting some `characters` to `numerics` doesn't mesh well. It really depends on what the scope is for this code. If you know that type x will always be within certain confines, you will probably be fine with their suggestion `class(y)<-class(x)`, but if you don't know what `x` will always be, you could end up trying to convert a `dataframe` into a `int`, which will throw an error. I would suggest approaching your problem a different way. With more information we may be able to help you find a more comprehensive solution to the problem. (I still can't comment yet, or this would be a comment).